# What is the function of dendritic cell in immunity?

Tags: immunology

I'm interested in how dendritic cells present antigens to  helper T-cells? I'm also interested in the molecular actions between a dendritic cell and a helper T-cell during the activation of the helper T-cell?  What function does the homing receptor on a T-cell have?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: In the inflammatory response, dendritic cells mainly function as [antigen-presenting cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antigen-presenting_cell), but the homing phenomenon happens under normal (non-inflammatory) conditions. Note that this is different from immune cell recruitment to the site of inflammation. You should specify under which context you'd like to know DC function.

Comment: @poka.nandor I must say the probability is high you are a good in-between lines reader :)... That edit...

Comment: @cagliari2005 - Thanks :) This seemed the most logical intention (at least for me) of the question based on title and the short description provided.

Answer (score 4):

Dendritic cells are so called professional antigen-presenting cells (APCs) as pointed out by Sleepes in comment section. They express both MHC-I and MHC-II receptors on their cell surface on which they present small peptides. These small peptides come from digested proteins of their own (MHC-I) or antigens that were phagocited or taken up by receptor mediated endocytosis (MHC-II). They also express costimulatory molecules necessary for the activation of T-cells (eg. CD80/CD86).

[image: T-cell activation]
source: http://journals.cambridge.org/fulltext_content/ERM/ERM2_09/S1462399400002143sup004.htm

As you can see in image above, activation of a T-cell requires two distinct signals: the recognition of an antigen and a co-stimulatory signal.

[image: diversification of t-cells]
source: http://www.mhhe.com/biosci/ap/dynamichuman2/content/gifs/0158.gif

After activation T-cells undergo rapid division and diversification.

Details of T-cell activation by dendritic cells can be found in this article for example:
[Immunol Cell Biol. 1997 Jun;75(3):223-30.
The role of dendritic cells in T cell activation.
Ni K1, O'Neill HC.](http://www.nature.com/icb/journal/v75/n3/pdf/icb199735a.pdf)